# EF DB Interceptor accessing context ( like current user and so on )

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6

I wrote my implementation of `IDbCommandTreeInterceptor` to modify queries based on context.

In my particular situation I need to access user object in interceptor, to determine what can a user do with table that has been queried.

It is my vision of implementing row-level security. In my DbInterceptor I get the user object, check for Roles and filter out rows where a user have no access.

Now my question.

I read some articles and understand that `DbInterceptors` may run in another thread (not in same where `HttpContext.Current` exist).

How to implement/organize this kind of things? I want to have access to context(what user is requesting and so on).

I am using `OData WebAPI`.

Comment: It's not good practice to access HttpContext.Current in your data access code. Perhaps you can inject this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for others. Don't do that. Ever. If you have this kind of problem, it means you have bad architecture. `DbInterceptors` are totally isolated and you should do something other.

I solve my problem by adding abstraction layer on top of `DbContext`.